# How do I run an entire php project in a web browser?

Tags: php

If I have a folder named "project", how do I open that on my computer as `http://www.example.com/project`?

My folder contains all sorts of scripts such as HTML and PHP, as well as other folders.
Is it possible to run the entire folder locally in a web browser?

[My project folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xR1xb.jpg)

Comment: WAY to broad, there is alot of information on this on the internet and your question is extremely broad

Comment: agree, be specific with what you want to achieve..if you haven't started anything yet, or trying to learn it..start by searching to internet

Comment: hie for example how to run a simple downloaded php project in localhost

Comment: If i were you i would install XAMPP (if you're on windows). You can find it here: https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html
Place your project in the C:\xampp\htdocs folder and then start the apache webserver from the XAMPP control panel.

Comment: @J.Mike1914, This is not right way to ask question... If you are new in php then you have to must read the php tutorials...

Comment: thank you NIckGames

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a [server-sided language](http://php.net/manual/en/intro-whatcando.php).
This means that it cannot just be opened in the same way that a self made .html can on your computer.

Install WAMP here: http://www.wampserver.com/en/

This will enable you to turn your localmachine into a server and then you can access that folder as:

```
http://localhost/index.php
```

Also, it probably isn't a good idea to call your files `register.html.php`